# How to improve test of react component with jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I need help for understand how to improve my test ?

I covered `branches` tests to 100% but can't do `statements` tests, `functions` tests and `lines` tests so how to covered these ?

**Here is my code-coverage (provided by jest):**
[image: code-coverage-img]

**And here is my test:**

```
/**
* Testing our ItemList component
*/
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import { BootstrapProvider } from 'bootstrap-styled';
import ItemList from '../index';

const renderComponent = (props = {}) => shallow(
  <BootstrapProvider>
    <ItemList {...props} />
  </BootstrapProvider>
);

describe('<ItemList />', () => {
  it('should render an <ItemList /> tag', () => {
    const renderedComponent = renderComponent();
    expect(renderedComponent.find('ItemList').length).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

Any advice are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you need to use `render` instead of `shallow` and then test the statements.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can see that the `this.props` is highlighted and that you have set within the component the props className with a className by default.

You could test the presence of the default className and also trying to set one:

```
it('should render an <ItemList /> with a className', () => {
    const renderedComponent = renderComponent({
        className:'className-test'
    });
expect(renderedComponent.find('ItemList').hasClass('className-test')).toEqual(true);
});

it('should render an <ItemList /> with a className 'item' by default ', () => {
     const renderedComponent = renderComponent(); 
expect(renderedComponent.find('ItemList').hasClass('item')).toEqual(true);
});
```

As for the rendering, I suggest you follow the advice given in the comment.